# willselectAnnotationView missing

Tags: iphone, mkannotationview, ios5.1, mkmapviewdelegate

In the MKMapViewDelegate, the code in the method mapView:didSelectAnnotationView is executed AFTER the selection of the annotation view (and therefore after the callout bubble appears).
BUT I need to execute some code BEFORE the callout bubble appears. So, I would need something like mapView:**Will**SelectAnnotationView ... that doesn't exist.
How can I do ?
Thank you !

Comment: Why can't it go in the didSelectAnnotationView?

Comment: Because I need to update the annotation BEFORE the callout bubble is displayed. If not, the callout bubble displays title and subtitle that doesn't match the actual situation.

Comment: Why not update the text on display, or even before that in the didAddannotations

Comment: You need to edit the annotation when you add it to the map, for responsiveness. There's no way you will get such a method.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this method to do the required functionality:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control;
```

Comment: That won't do it either, that isn't called until someone hits the button on the bubble!!!!